# jquery autocomplete/type to select from list

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Does the jquery UI (or other) autocomplete plugin allow me to know if the text in the textbox is still an item selected from the list?

I want users to be able to type, get an autocomplete menu and choose an item. If they continue typing or delete characters etc, i need to know that the item has been deselected.

Is this possible without customisation?

Is there a better plugin or approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There's the facebook style input box, is this the kind of thing your after? http://ajaxian.com/archives/facebook-style-input-box

---

**Edit**

The jQuery UI autocomplete sets a data object on the input element that you can access through `.data()` like so:

```
$('input').data('autocomplete').selectedItem.value;
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/qK3MA/1/

Comment: no, i just want a sort of filterable list. although +1 for that cool plugin

Comment: i only want to be able to select one item